# Снятие выделения кнопки, расположенной на месте предыдущей

Tags: css, ios, bootstrap, hover

Проблема присутствует на iOS устройствах: есть 5 кнопок в ряд (это оценки *отлично*, *хорошо* и т.д.), после нажатия на кнопку на след. странице кнопка, расположенная на месте предыдущей, остается выделенной (*hover*).

Вот [сайт](http://concor.me/oprosnik/)

Пробовал снимать *hover*. менять цвет *border* при загрузке страницы и т.п.

Comment: В вопрос стоит добавить [краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода, демонстрирующий данную проблему.

Comment: ссылка мертвая...